# React: Props - Why does one work, but another not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following Problem:

When I enter the URL to my image directly in the component, it works and gets displayed:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Service.css';

class Service extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="logo">{this.props.serviceName}</h2>
        <img src={require("../../images/project_management.jpg")} width="150" alt="Smiley face" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Service;
```

But when I send the image url through the "props" from the outer component it does not work, although ist the exact same string. I get "Error: Cannot find module '../../images/project_management.jpg'"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import Service from './modules/Service';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="outer-container">
        <div className="inner-container">
          <Service serviceName="Project Manager" img="../../images/project_management.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Service.css';

class Service extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="logo">{this.props.serviceName}</h2>
        <img src={require(this.props.img)} width="150" alt="Smiley face" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Service;
```

Can anybody give me a hint?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: The solution might be to not use relative paths at all.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably (you have to confirm this) you are using webpack and an image loader to load the content. Webpack will make a static analysis to understand which static assets it needs to include, however, when you make a dynamic require (this means, require a variable) like `require(this.props.image)` webpack has no idea at bunndle time of what you want to load.
The solution is to always load the full path to the image, then pass that on props:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import Service from './modules/Service';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="outer-container">
        <div className="inner-container">
          <Service serviceName="Project Manager" img={require("../../images/project_management.jpg")} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Service.css';

class Service extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="logo">{this.props.serviceName}</h2>
        <img src={this.props.img} width="150" alt="Smiley face" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Service;
```

This is the correct way of doing it if you are using any image bundler that works like I described.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path to image instead of relative

```
<Service serviceName="Project Manager" img={absoltePathToImage} />
```

Service tries to find the image relative to it's path and fails

If you want to use relative paths(bad idea)

Use

```
<Service serviceName="Project Manager" img="../../../images/project_management.jpg" />
```

As service is one layer deeper to Home

Answer (score 0):

instead of using require like one in your code

```
<img src={require("../../images/project_management.jpg")} width="150" alt="Smiley face" />
```

you should provide and url directly to src atrib and use it as:

```
<img src={this.props.img} width="150" alt="Smiley face" />
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you. Moving the "require"-Statement to the outer component solved the problem:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import Service from './modules/Service';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="outer-container">
        <div className="inner-container">
          <Service serviceName="Project Manager" img={require("../images/project_management.jpg")} />
          <Service serviceName="Software Engineer" img={require("../images/project_management3.jpg")} />
          <Service serviceName="Web Developer" img={require("../images/web_development.jpg")} />
        </div>
        <div className="inner-container">
          <Service serviceName="Requirements Enigneer" img={require("../images/requirements_engineering.jpg")} />
          <Service serviceName="Quality Manager" img={require("../images/quality_management.jpg")} />
          <Service serviceName="Trainer" img={require("../images/trainer.jpg")} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```